# How to generate right sql for using hstore in rails migration postgres using change_column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, hstore

I need to get hstore working in a rails migration. I have enabled hstore through a migration, now, I am trying to generate the correct sql to get it working but when I run db:migrate I get this error;

```
C:\Sites\Peoples_Profiles>rails db:migrate
rails aborted!
SyntaxError: C:/Sites/Peoples_Profiles/db/migrate/20180407073155_add_hstore_hash_to_urls.rb:4: syntax error, unexpected '\n', expecting =>
C:/Sites/Peoples_Profiles/db/migrate/20180407073155_add_hstore_hash_to_urls.rb:10: syntax error, unexpected end-of-input, expecting keyword_end
bin/rails:4:in `require'
bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

The migration looks like this.

```
class AddHstoreHashToUrls < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]

  def self.up
    change_column :users, :urls, default: {}, "hstore USING urls::hstore" 
  end

  def self.down
    change_column :users, :urls, :text
  end
end
```

What is the correct sql to get the type set for that column and why am I get a newline error?

**UPDATE**
My urls are getting stored like this in db

```
 urls: {"url1"=>"", "url2"=>"", "url3"=>"", "url4"=>"", "url5"=>""}
```

so I think postgres is complaining because it is trying to convert this code..

So after check how rails actually brings in paramaters it looks like this

```
 ["urls", "--- !ruby/hash:ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess\nurl1: http://hello\nurl2: http://jack\nurl3: http://boo\nurl4: ''\nurl5: ''\n"]
```

Not sure if it looks like this in the db unfortunetly but I say there is a \n in there some where causing this error. Will have to pursue this further.

... and I realise now the \n will be coming from the conversion of serializing a hash to YAML.

Comment: I am going to try and do a create_table just to see if its just migrating over..

Comment: Ok, so if I do `add_column :users, :urlss, :hstore, default: {}, null: false` and add a new column it works so i think it has trouble changing and converting format

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presumably you started with:

```
serialize :urls
```

in your model so your hashes are being stored in the database as YAML. There is no type cast from YAML text to `hstore` so your USING:

```
USING urls::hstore
```

won't work. There's no easy way to reliably parse YAML inside PostgreSQL so your best bet is to:

1. Rename the `users.urls` column to `users.yaml_urls`.
2. Add a new `urls` column with (preferably) `jsonb` type but you can use `hstore` if necessary. `jsonb` is the future and will be better supported going forward.
3. Read each `yaml_urls` value from the database into Ruby.
4. Convert that YAML string to hash with `h = YAML.load(yaml_from_db)`.
5. Encode the hash as JSON (`h.to_json`) and put it back in the database.
6. Make `urls` NOT NULL if desired and drop the `yaml_urls` column.

I'd recommend using the low level [pg interface](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/ged/ruby-pg) for this as you don't want ActiveRecord stuff in the way, can you find such a connection in `ApplicationRecord.connection.raw_connection`. I say this because you don't want data migrations interacting with models in any way and the low level interface supports placeholders so you can avoid escaping and quoting issues.

That process assumes that you don't have that much data or, equivalently, your app can be offline while you fix the database. If that's not the case then you'd need to maintain both formats (add a new `jsonb` column, write to and read from both inside your model when `urls` and `urls=` are called) while you fix the data, and then clean up later.

Comment: So your saying I could use either pg gem or `ApplicationRecord.connection.raw_connection` I couldn't find anything on that. I have pg gem already installed. And your saying I can run all this code after I make a connection. Then mix my ruby with sql to achieve results?

Comment: You can find a `PG::Connection` in `ApplicationRecord.connection.raw_connection` or just `connection.raw_connection` in a migration. I linked to the `pg` documentation in the answer. Then you have to fix everything up row by row by hand with a mix of SQL (to get data and put new data back) and Ruby (to decode YAML and encode as JSON). Yes, this is an ugly process but it is the inevitable result of using `serialize`.

Answer (score -1):

Try to change the SELF.DOWN to SELF.ANNUAL
I think its will solve

Comment: And you didn't closed the line(see line 4)

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: I do not think you need to close the line I think rails does that automatically..